# Using "This way" to repeat and conclude

Tags: sentence-construction

Can I use "This way" to say my intention from the previous sentence? Are there other ways to do that?

> In particular, we employ the textual delimiters and semantic cues within a web page to locate the data of interest. **This way**, we try to simulate the way a human user scans a web page top-down or bottom-up to find a specific data in the page.

---

<sub>As for the **Tags** of this question, I don't know what such words called (the words to relate two sentence, like: *however, in other words, as a result*....)</sub>

Comment: I think "*this way*" is a short for "*By doing it this way*".  Not sure if it helps.

Comment: Or "In this way..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct phrase would be, "In this way," for this context. You can also use, "That way, we can try to simulate...", or what sounds stronger, "That way, we can simulate..."